# Function call and user input file name with extentions in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. After finishing the tutorials I am trying to build small apps to improve myself. I am making little console diary program as you can see.

```
import os
def greetings():
    name = input("Who is using program : ")
    return "Hello "+name+" welcome to the diary."
def what_todo():
    print("What would you like to do today ?")
    print("Taking notes (1) \nReading notes (2)")
    choice = int(input())
    return choice
def do():
    if what_todo() == 1:
        file_name = input("Please name today's diary :  ")
        f = open(file_name,"w")
        f.write(input())
        f.close()
    elif what_todo() == 2:
        file_name = input("Which diary you want to read : ")
        if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            f = open(file_name,"r")
            for x in f:
                print(x)
        else:
            print("file does not exist")

def main():
    print(greetings())

    do()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have three things to ask :

- When i call `if what_todo() == 1:` it runs the what_todo() function
  but I only want the return of the what_todo() function and of course print's are repeating itself in the second call for elif statement. Is there a way to do it or I am going all wrong? Like unnecessary functions or anything else.
- I am getting user input for file name it is okay but I want to create
  file as a ".txt" or maybe ".data". How do I do that?
- One last thing. As a newbie, if you would like to share I want your
  opinion about the code I wrote or advice about it.

Thank you for your answers.
Output :

```
This is the output : 
hilal@crescent:~/Diary$ python diary.py
Who is using program : L
Hello L welcome to the diary.
What would you like to do today ?
Taking notes (1) 
Reading notes (2)
1
Please name today's diary :  a
aaa
hilal@crescent:~/Diary$ python diary.py 
Who is using program : L
Hello L welcome to the diary.
What would you like to do today ?
Taking notes (1) 
Reading notes (2)
2
What would you like to do today ?
Taking notes (1) 
Reading notes (2)
2
Which diary you want to read : a
aaa
```

Comment: for code reviews, try the Code Review community - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wil try it, thank you! @PrasadK

Comment: I don't quite get your first point, what is the problem?

Comment: I added the output @Fozoro

Comment: I just ran your code and it looks great! the only edit I would do is change `print("What would you like to do today ?")
    print("Taking notes (1) \nReading notes (2)")` to `print("What would you like to do today ?\nTaking notes (1) \nReading notes (2)")?`to make your code neater thought this is a minor change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, those `print`s are redundant as their only purpose seems to show  messages to the user. If you want to show some text to the user upon `input`-ing input value, you should pass the string as `input` function's argument e.g.:

   ```
   input("What would you like to do today ?")
   ```

   Also, I would check for `TypeError` when changing type to `int` from `str` in `choice = int(input())` e.g. when the input is `foobar`.
2. Filenames are strings, so you can append the desired extension to the user inputted file name string e.g.:

   ```
   final_file_name = '{}.txt'.format(file_name)
   ```

   will get a `.txt` extension. Also check if user has not inputted the extension already.
3. If you're interested in a thorough review, please ask on [CodeReviewSE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for input in `what_todo()` and you only want to call it once. So you need to call it once and save the value it returns. There are lots of ways to do that but here is one:

```
def main():
    print(greetings())
    action = what_todo()
    do(action)

def do(action):
    if action == 1:
```

You can add an extension to the filename like this:

```
file_name = input("Please name today's diary :  ") + ".txt"
```

Though in a real program you would also need to verify that the input filename is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the `what_todo()` function and save the returned value in a variable. Then later use the variable in the if conditions.

regarding filename - once you get an input from the user, you can append any extension you want by using the `+` operator. `file_name` is just a string. So you can update it as you see fit -

```
file_name += '.txt'
```